# pre-made jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an example like this on the jquery website:

```
$( "div" ).addClass(function( index, currentClass ) {
  var addedClass;

  if ( currentClass === "red" ) {
    addedClass = "green";
    $( "p" ).text( "There is one green div" );
  }

  return addedClass;
});
```

In regards to 'index' and 'currentClass', are these DOM objects? What exactly are these, and how would one find a list of them? i often see 'e' in here and also don't understand that.

Thank you

Comment: They are function parameters. The only *"list"* you may find of them would be at the api documentation. http://api.jquery.com

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/addclass/#addClass-functionindex--currentClass

Comment: You should start by learning some JavaScript (or any other language) programming notions. Then go back to learning a library like jQuery.

Comment: [It's right there in the jQuery documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

> A function returning one or more space-separated class names to be added to the existing class name(s). Receives the **index position of the element** in the set and **the existing class name(s)** as arguments. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

So, no. they aren't DOM objects. One will be a number, the other will be a string (containing a space separated list of class names).

Comment: I guess to re-iterate my question; does .addClass only accept the function parameters of 'index' and 'currentClass'? Or are there more things to plug in there? That's kind of what i meant by a list.. Are these built-in jquery functions within themselves?

Comment: `addClass` doesn't accept those arguments at all. It accepts a function which accepts two arguments. Only those two arguments are accepted. The documentation tells you this. You can call the arguments whatever you like.

Comment: Ok! I see. So basically it is strict. If the API says it accepts this function that uses these arguments, then that's all that is allowed.